# Android - VideoView taking focus of activity

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, focus, android-videoview

I have a list of videoViews, but because videoView takes the focus by default, the activity it is in will start somewhere halfway the activity where the videos are.

How can I stop the video from taking focus so my activity starts on the top like normal? I use API 21 and kotlin.